# java objects shared among multiple threads, when garbage collected?

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

Working on a program with huge memory issues. 
The program consists of two threads. Thread 1 picks up data from a queue, processes them, creates various objects and passes them to Thread 2 for processing and storing in db. 
The Used Heap size kept climbing up until and OutOfMemory error occurred.

I resolved the memory issue by using only one thread, because from what I could understand, objects ended up remaining alive and hence not GC-ed as references to them remained throughtout Thread 2 and the db storing process.

I still have a question: when would the objects created in thread 1 be expected to be GC-ed ? when thread 1 exits ? when thread 2, which would use them for further processing, would exit ?

Answer (score 0):

> when would the objects created in thread 1 be expected to be GC-ed?

Whenever the GC likes, subject to them being collectable. Maybe never.

> when thread 1 exits ? when thread 2, which would use them for further processing, would exit ?

None of the above. They become collectable when unreachable, i.e. when all references to them have gone out of scope, or the containing objects have become unreachable. A thread is always reachable while it is executing.

Comment: So there could be two things contributing to making the program very memory intensive (besides the creation of big objects), 1) thread 2 responsible for db persistence was slow, and  kept references to these objects for a long time and 2) the containing object, i.e. the thread, is always reachable and so would the objects created in it

Comment: @user2163389 the question is why any thread can still refer to an object after it has been processed, that certainly shouldn't be the case

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information here, but I will venture a guess that your are "passing" objects from Thread 1 to Thread 2 using a queue and you are running out of memory because Thread 1 generates "objects" faster than Thread 2 is able to consume them (write them to the database).

If this is indeed true, you can limit the size of the queue yourself or use something like a LinkedBlockingQueue with a predefined capacity. You may also be able to speed things up by creating more instances of Thread 2 (provided they work can be executed in parallel), although if the bottleneck is the database, there may be little you can do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, your guess is correct, that is precisely what is going on. My question though was in trying to understand if objects created in Thread 1 and consumed in Thread 2 would/could be GC-ed when Thread 2 finish saving them to DB. or whether these objects are totally dependent on  Thread 1